# Django: return decimal instead of strange object

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model with a decimal field.  The output of:

```
def special_method(self):
    return MyClass.objects.filter(product=self).order_by('-date_active')[0:1]
```

on this model is:

```
[<MyClass: 10.00>]
```

... and I have defined the following method on MyClass:

```
def __str__(self):
    return str(self.rate)
```

This may be a silly question but how do I correctly return the decimal number instead of this strange object?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`myclass_instance.rate` will give you the decimal number.

[edit]

Your method will then be something like:

```
def special_method(self):
    return MyClass.objects.filter(product=self).order_by('-date_active')[:1].values_list('rate', flat=True)
```

Or you might be able to do something like:

```
def special_method(self):
    return self.myclass_set.order_by('-date_active')[:1].values_list('rate', flat=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using `filter`, which always returns a QuerySet - a list-like collection of multiple instances - even if only one item is matched. You should use `.get()` instead, which will return a single item, and then you can access the `.rate` property on the returned instance.

Comment: I don't think this is possible, because the characteristics of my specific model mean that multiple objects will usually be returned for the given input.